# Optimized bundles returning 404 when requesting from the website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, umbraco7

I'm having this weird problem when I set:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

When I try to open my website it just won't load, when I open Chrome's console I see the following message:

GET /localhost/bundles/scripts/angularjs/commonmodules?v=13-uWpwzN3U6kiHVssXRdpywHxrn09twvYKwoDVN3SU1 404 (Not Found)

However, if I try to open the link shown on chrome's console, it loads just fine, in other words, the link is found when I try to open it directly, but the server (IIS 7.5) returns a 404 when a page tries to link it through a  tag.

Have anyone been through such a weird behavior?

The virtual paths for my bundles do not map for any existing file or directory, I include them using the following code:

```
var myBundle= new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/angularjs/bootstrapping");
bootstrapping.Include("~/app/app.js")
    .Include("~/app/config.js")
    .Include("~/app/config.exceptionHandler.js")
    .Include("~/app/config.route.js");
bundles.Add(bootstrapping);
```

And I already tried to add the following lines on web.config's system.webServer:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="BundleModule" />
    <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

I'm not sure if this may be related, but I'm using Umbraco v7 on this website, and this only happens if I set EnableOptimizations to "true".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I remember correctly it's umbraco config related.

Locate the key `umbracoReservedPaths` (in `appSettings`) in your `web.config`  and add the path to bundles there, like so:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/bundles/"/>
```

Comment: thank you so much! adding "~/bundles/" and "~/app/" to umbracoReservedPaths did the job!

Comment: OMG - Three years, I have been trying to find this out. This works!!! I am currently using v4.7, v7.5, and v7.6.3. (+1)

Comment: Adding my bundling paths in umbracoReservedPaths, fixed this for me. Thanks!